# Debugging and Loglevels for Kubernetes Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When calling `helm template ...` I get this error:

```
Error: YAML parse error on `myfile.yaml`: error converting YAML to JSON: `yaml`: line 60: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

I would like to know, if I can set debug options to analyze this problem.
Because `myfile.yaml` is valid in another context with other values, it would be helpful, if I could print out the generated invalid `yaml` before helm tries to convert it to `json`.

There are [options --debug and -v](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/) but these don't help.

**Remarks**

There is another [question with the same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076858/kubernetes-helm-chart-debugging). But that question is about a specific problem. My question is not about a specific problem. Instead I would like to get **general hints**, how to analyze such problems.

Comment: as far as I remember 'helm template --dry-run --debug' does not validate the template/yaml. This should print out the yaml as proposed to the kubernetes api. Why exactly is that not enough to server your use case? ps a way to ignore parse errors is to comment out the affected section in the template and rendert it

Comment: That's the solution! Now I see directly the error in the generated yaml. When you post this as an answer, I will accept it then. Thanks!

Comment: I've stripped down your answer to the actual solution. hope that's ok.

Comment: Answer to your questions: I didn't expect, that --dry-run had this effect on helm template, because I thought, helm template is already a dry-run without install. But obviously I was wrong here. Commenting out the affected section does not always help, if the error is connected to indenting errors for example. So thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`helm template --dry-run --debug` does not validate the template/yaml.

This should print out the yaml as proposed to the kubernetes api.